# django model's inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I want to have two registration type. for example : employee and employer type. i want two different form.
i override AbstractUser and after i use this class (inheritance)

```
class User(AbstractUser):
  
  age=models.BooleanField(default=True)


class employee(User):
  is_employee=models.BooleanField(default=True)
  ser=models.BooleanField()
  sag=models.CharField(max_length=1)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name="employee"


class employer(User):
  is_employer=models.BooleanField(default=True)
  address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

but when i save employee or employer class also created User class. can i do when i save only employee save just that and not User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on the state of the User table - the way you have it now there will be a User table and a Employee table and a One to One relationship.

If you want it so that both the Employee and Employer Table includes an 'age' attribute you have to make the User table abstract.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

The way to do this is :

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    class Meta:
          abstract = True
    
    age=models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Even though you have inherited from Abstract User, I wouldn't assume that the Meta settings are inherited.